# Count the number of the same letters in 2 strings

Tags: python

I need to count how many of shared letters are in 2 strings.

```
s1="hello"
s2="leeo"

def shared(s1, s2):
    for letter in s2:
        if letter in s1:
            find = s2.count(s1)
            print(find)
```

The output it gives me:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
None
```

But it suppose to be:

```
3
```

I'm kinda lost on this one.

Comment: I guess it's a duplicate, search for sets intersection on SO

Comment: There should be something like `s1.count(letter)`, we are counting how often the `letter` appears in `s1`, don't we?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you count the occurrence of `'hello'` in the string `'leo'`, which is exactly 0 because the string `'hello'` does not exist in `'leo'`.

In your case, variable `letter` holds the values `'l'`, `'e'`, `'o'` one after another within your loop. To make your code work, change the line to

`find = s1.count(letter)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```py
s1="hello"
s2="leo"

def shared(s1, s2):
  find = 0

  for letter in s2:
      if letter in s1:
          find += 1
  return find

print(shared(s1, s2))
```